# Rails help rewriting random mysql finder to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My controller:

```
def toppen
@top = Konkurrancer
end
```

My view:

```
<ul id="random">
<% @top.find(:all, :limit => 5, :order => 'rand()').each do |vind| %>
<li><%= link_to vind.name.force_encoding("UTF-8"), konkurrance_path(vind.kategori.cached_slug, vind.cached_slug) %></li>
 <% end %>
 </ul>
```

How do I rewrite this to PostgreSQL?

Comment: That's just the `ORDER BY` part of a normal SQL query between the quotes, so you can use Google to search for Postgre- or MySql-specific syntax. As @Mike Lewis points out, finders in your views violate separation of concerns (i.e., controllers talk to the DB, views should not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL random is used by calling RAND().

In PostreSQL random is used by calling RANDOM().

So it would be:

```
<% @top.find(:all, :limit => 5, :order => 'random()').each do |vind| %>
```

On another note, you should never use ActiveRecord in your views. I'd read up on the concept of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).